# Perl hash add values

Tags: perl, perl-hash

I am trying to push values into hash. I want to add the values under 'par3'.
e.g.

```
$VAR1 = { 'obj1' => ['par1', 
                     'par2', 
                     'par3' => ['par4','par5','par6',....]]}
```

I should also be able to add elements into 'par3' in case 'obj1'-'par1'-'par2'-'par3' matches.
So far I have this, but I can't figure out how can I add "the second level" under 'par3':

```
push @{$a{$obj}},$par1,$par2,$par3
```

Comment: `['par1', 'par2', 'par3' => [ 'par4', 'par5', 'par6' ] ]` is just a weird way of writing `['par1', 'par2', 'par3', [ 'par4', 'par5', 'par6' ] ]` (a reference to an array four elements). Is that really what you want?

Comment: Every time I look at your question, I come up with a new question. It's extremely unclear what you want. The code shows that you are pushing par1, par2 and par3. But the dump shows these are the first values. So why is a push being used? , Are you asking for `$VAR1->{ obj1 } = [ 'par1', 'par2', 'par3', [ 'par4', 'par5', 'par6' ] ];`? If not, please explain why this would not do.

Comment: e.g. What's does the structure look before the operation you want to perform, and what do you want it to look like after. Please clarify your answer by editing it, not by adding comments (though feel free to leave a comment that contains `@ikegami` to let me know you've made these changes).

Answer (score 1):

`[ ... ]` is a reference to an array. Array elements are scalars. So it is not possible to directly have the structure you seem to be requesting (ie. the `par3 => [ ... ]` pseudocode from your question). See [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc)

It's not obvious what you are trying to do but a couple of possible ideas might be to use a reference to a hash, or to replace the array with a hash:

```
use Data::Dumper;

$Var2a = {
    'obj1' => [
        'par1', 
        'par2', 
        { 'par3' => undef, }
    ],
};

push @{ $Var2a->{obj1}[2]{par3} }, 'par4', 'par5', 'par6';
print Dumper $Var2a;

$Var2b = {
    'obj1' => {
        'par1' => undef, 
        'par2' => undef, 
        'par3' => undef,
    },
};

push @{ $Var2b->{obj1}{par3} }, 'par4', 'par5', 'par6';
print Dumper $Var2b;
```

Comment: I actually want to have in the key 'obj1' single values 'par1','par2','par3' and an array (list of elements) which contains {'par4','par5','par6',...}

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add children to par3. As such, I think you want pars to have children. If so, you need a different data structure.

```perl
# Ordered
my $obj1 = [
   { name => 'par1', children => [ ] },
   { name => 'par2', children => [ ] },
   { name => 'par3', children => [
      { name => 'par4', children => [ ] },
      { name => 'par5', children => [ ] },
      { name => 'par6', children => [ ] },
   ] },
];
```

or

```perl
# Unordered
my $obj1 = {
   par1 => { },
   par2 => { },
   par3 => {
      par4 => { },
      par5 => { },
      par6 => { },
   },
};
```

To append par7 to par3's children, you would use

```perl
# Ordered

use List::Util qw( first );

my $par7 = { name => 'par7', children => [ ] };

my $par3 = first { $_->{ name } eq 'par3' } @$obj1
   or die( "par3 not found" );

push @{ $par3->{ children } }, $par7;
```

or

```perl
# Unordered

$obj1->{ par3 }{ par7 } = { };
```